# Derivation of a parameter in optimization problem

Tags: calculus, optimization, self-learning, linear-programming, economics

My question

[image]

The solution for first part

$$L=(aq+1-a)x1x2+\lambda (y-(a(p1+c)+(1-a)p1)x1-x2p2)$$

As a result after FOCs

$$x1=\frac {y}{2(a(p1+c)+(1-a)p1)}$$

$$x2={y\over 2*p2}$$

The solution for the second part

$$\lambda (a(p1+c)+(1-a)p1)= (aq+1-a)x2$$

$$\lambda (a(p1+c)+(1-a)p1)= (aq+1-a){y\over 2*p2}$$

$$a(qy-y-2p2\lambda c)=2p2\lambda p1-y$$

$$a={2p2\lambda p1-y\over a(qy-y-2p2\lambda c)}$$

I would like to ask for the second part.

The first part solution is just informative. Please don’t interest on its solution. But for the second part, I have tried to derive alpha. But, I guess this result for the value of alpha is wrong. Please tell me what you think about deriving of alpha. How can I do it if it is wrong?